# Failed to execute goal Could not exec java

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jaas, spring-boot-2

Recently I was upgraded `spring-boot` version `1.5.x` to `2.4.3`.
After upgrading `spring-boot` it won't start.

ran command `mvn clean spring-boot run`

Then spring throw the error :

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:run (default-cli) on project sample-project: Could not exec java
```

Java version : `1.8` Maven version : `3.6.3`

If any information is required then please comment, I will update the question as per the requirement.

Comment: I am currently having the same issue and I am looking for an explanation.
You may want to give more infortion on your question. Like the project structure and the poms you are using.